# HTML - Use of posts inside tag ul > li

Tags: php, html

HTML Question, Understand Post as a dynamic generated PHP content.

Would it make sense for posts to be put inside ul > li tags? Or to use nested divs?

I've seen youtube do this for their videos, google search for the results, twitter for their feeds, all inside a list.

So would it make more sense semantically?

Comment: what u r talking abt ?

Comment: This could be argued for days with no resolution.

Comment: @Bhavin Rana I'm so sorry i just edited it to be better understood.

Comment: @leftclickben well, i suppose so, that's the doubt i'm having and i'm starting to think it doesn't matter :/

Comment: I wouldn't say it doesn't matter, it just doesn't have a single correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on you, how you want your post wrapper element to be, for example stackoverflow uses `div`

```
<div id="question-summary-id" class="question-summary">
```

So semantically both are correct, there's no thumb rule for this, on the other hand you can make use of `HTML5` tags to represent data like date/time, post body can be wrapped inside an `article` tag, different posts can be wrapped inside `section` tag, etc